# how to draw a quadratic/cubic bezier curve in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

Suppose I have these control points in Inkscape
[image]

I want to draw two curves, one is a quadratic bezier curve, the other is a cubic bezier curve.

We know they are:

`q=(1-t)^2 * p0 + 2 * t * (1-t) * p1 + t^2 * p2`

`c=(1-t)^3 * p0 + 3 * t * (1-t)^2 * p1 + 3 * (1-t) * t^2 * p2 + t^3 p3`

I used the Inkscape bezier tool, but the curve doesn't seem to be the one I want. Does any one know how to draw these two curves precisely?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much *all* curves in Inkscape are basically cubic Bezier curves. For your example with the four points, first make sure your Bezier tool is set to 'Create regular Bezier path' ([image: Mode Button in toolbar]) and add a line connecting P<sub>0</sub> to P<sub>3</sub>:

[image: Example from question with simple line connecting P0 and P3]

Then shift-drag the nodes with the node-tool, adding handles to them, and drag those to points P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> on each side:

[image: Example from above with handles put on control points P1 and P2]

As for quadratic curves, I don't think there is an easy way to draw them with Inkscape's drawing tools (there *is* a BSpline-mode, but that's not quite the same). However, you can use the 'Edit → XML Editor...' to manually edit the path-data in the `d`-attribute, entering your coordinates and [using the 'q/Q' commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands):

[image: Creating a qubic curve using the XML-editor]

In this example, the `m 100,80` part is the coordinates of P<sub>0</sub>, then `Q 222,106` for P<sub>1</sub> and the last pair (`311,-31`) is P<sub>2</sub>.

By the way, this method also lets you directly specify cubic curves [with the 'c/C' commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) (e.g. something like `m 100,50 C 150,50 150,200 50,200`).